# Guidance to combine 2 events in discord.py (one receives the reaction of the user and its emoji, and the other waits for a specific user message)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, computer-science

How to write a program in discord.py to get reaction from a user but prints the result only when the user enters a message ("!info"). I'm able to individually code each one of them but i am not sure how to combine them.

**ik "reaction", "user" variables won't be able to be accessed in the 2nd decorator. So, the question is how to solve that syntax issue?**

```
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction,user):

        users = set()
        async for user in reaction.users():
        
                 users.add(user)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    
        if message.content.startswith("!info"):
                channel=reaction.message.channel
                await channel.send (f"{user} reacted with {reaction.emoji}")
                await channel.send(f" list of users: {', '.join(user.name for user in users)}")
```

Comment: Store `user.id` from `on_reaction_add` somewhere e.g. database (or json, will do it for this temporary thing) and check if it's the same id as `message.author.id` in `on_message`. If it's the same, send the message.

Comment: i dont really know how to work with either a database or json, is there any other way?

Comment: use cogs. It's used with a class. See here for more: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/cogs.html?highlight=cogs